# Xamarin how can i get all system notification?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new here. I'm developing an app that is using google maps when i press a FAT button. As at the moment google maps does not indicate when you finished a Navigation and so to be able to return to my application, I am trying to do this in some way.
I was thinking, and google maps when you're in navigation mode, it shows you a notification. Until the navigation is finished, it is not deleted. I wanted to get this notification and when my button was pressed, check if the notification is active. In case it is not active, then I can return to my application.
This is what i've been trying to do:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager =
          GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                            StatusBarNotification[] nnn2 = notificationManager.GetActiveNotifications();
```

When i check nnn2 to see what services are active, it has nothing. I don't know if i need to add some permissions in manifest, or i'm totally wrong.

Comment: `getActiveNotifications` returns the notifications that are still available to the user from just your app (the caller of this method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible and can be done something like this:

For levels below API 11 :

```
 Notification notify = new Notification();
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound;
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
            notify.Flags = NotificationFlags.NoClear;// Cruicial line of code
```

For API 11 and above:

```
 Notification notify = new Notification();
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound;
            notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
            notify.Flags = NotificationFlags.NoClear;

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
             .SetContentTitle(messageTitle)
             .SetContentText(messageBody)
             .SetOngoing(true)//Important line of code
             .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
 NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
```